# How do I kill a slime in a radius of 50?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I kill a slime in a radius of 50?

I looked up a bunch of different solutions but none of them seemed to work. So I figured that is because they are outdated. Anyone able to help would be awesome. I'm using version 1.12.2.

I tried the following:

- `/execute @e[type=Slime,r=50]`,
- `/kill @e[r=50,type=slime]`,
- `/tp @e[r=50,type=slime] ~ ~-200 ~`.

Any ideas?

Comment: The second command does what you want. What is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments it looks like you're playing on a modded server. Since some plugins override default Minecraft commands, such as Essentials, these don't work like they do in vanilla anymore.

To use the vanilla Minecraft command in Bukkit or Spigot, try adding a prefix to the kill command, for example:

```
/minecraft:kill @e[type=slime,r=50]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that solved the issue that we've been having for 11 months everyone was to scared to ask though. Lol Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Your question is vague. "It doesn't work" means nothing to us. What do you expect your command to do? How does the result differ from what you desire? What did it do instead? Did you get any errors? Be precise. Nevertheless I have written an answer for you which I think comes closest to what you want.

The `execute` command is used to execute commands from a specific entity and/or location. It has nothing to do with the removal of entities.

The `kill` command is used to remove entities as if they are killed by natural causes. This one is not useful for slimes, because slimes split into smaller slimes when killed, unless that's what you desire. The command would be as follows:

```
/kill @e[type=Slime,r=50]
```

The `tp` command is used to teleport entities to a given location. This one is more useful for slimes, since this one takes care of all slimes in all sizes. The disadvantage is that you don't get the itemdrops if you desire those.
The command is as follows:

```
/tp @e[type=Slime,r=50] ~ ~-500 ~
```

I used -500 because the buildlimit is 256 and therefore, one cannot find a slime which gets to heights above 500 by itself.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to make it vague.
When I put it in the command block and use the button nothing happens, no errors or anything and command blocks are on I did /butcher in the block and it works. 

I tried those two and it didn't seem to work. I'm not sure if I shouldn't be coping and pasting it. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong or if I need to explain further.

Comment: @xXMrMoose the `butcher` command is not part of the vanilla game, which leads me to believe that you are playing with mods. In that case I cannot help you, because then I can only make wild guesses as to what can and cannot be done. If you say that `/butcher` works, then I suppose you should use that.

Comment: The butcher command is a plugin. I play on a hockey server that involves a lot of practice with the puck(slime) so players at the other rinks will reset the puck(butcher) and it kills all of the slimes. If it was kill a slime in 50 radius then it would prevent that accident from happening.